# Chrome can't download but other browser can ... html link on mp4

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i try to add a simple link for download video in http://www.netcamstudio.com/ ...
the webinterface is on GPL licence ...

So i juste add :

```
$('.outPopUp').append('<a href="'+ directory.getLibraryURL(data.Id, data.ItemType, false) +
'" download="'+data.Id+'"><img src="./img/download.png" class="downloadButton" tabindex="1" /></a>');
```

On all web browser this is work exept on chrome ...

i have link like : 
    http://192.168.1.96:8100/Library/201610170122.mp4?authToken=4b0ea803-f831-44fb-965f-e8ea77bae1c1

if a follow the link in chrome i can see the video ... but can't download !
( Chrome say link is not found )

any idea why ?

Comment: The download attribute sure works in Chrome, so it has to be the content that can't be found?

Comment: if i a travel to the url , i can see the video in chrome ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ...

The api of netcamstudio have a little bug ... and say the video size is 0 ...